# GameCenter Sandbox and beta tests

Tags: ios, xcode, sandbox, game-center

I would like to know how it works: if I have now my game working with GameCenter and want to release app for tests (AdHoc) then account of everyone, who will sign in to GameCenter, will become "Sandbox" state?

You know I don't want to hassle my testers, if it's so as I thought, I maybe should disable GC for beta tests?

Tell me please, how it works and what should I do.
I see my 3 accounts I used for my own testing became "Sandbox". How to repair that and restore normal state?

Answer (score 3):

My beta testers have Sandbox accounts. To restore it to the normal mode, you should simply sign out from the game center app and then login within an App Store game.

Comment: What is a "Sandbox Accounts" ? I spent hours on StackOverflow, Apple's forum and Apples'documentation but things still not clear to me.
Does AdHoc testers have to do some specific action to test Game Center game or not ?

Comment: think of a Sandbox account as a closed duplicate of game center servers. It acts exactly like Game Center but it is invisible to users who are not signed up from the sandbox account, Apple did this so that games that are not live yet (but in production) do not show up in other peoples Game Center feeds. As for the AdHoc testers, no they don't have to do anything, iOS is configured such that Game center automatically logs into sandbox servers with an app that is not downloaded from App Store (signed by Apple)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kaan.
The following sentence still confused me, "It acts exactly like Game Center but it is invisible to users who are not signed up from the sandbox account" :
Who are those "users who are no signed up from the sandbox account" ?
When do you sign for this sandbox account ?

Comment: You don't sign up for a different account, your username-password combination still works. What I wanted to say is this in short sentences: When a game in production (not in the App Store) logs into Game Center, iOS automatically logs you in the game center in a sandbox mode, everything behaves the same but the activity is hidden from users who are logged into regular Game Center (non-developers who are not testing a game in production). So there's no signing up, the experience is the same as well.